# Start incoming call by adb on a real android device

Tags: android, adb, incoming-call

My pc does not support android emulator and i need to make fake incoming calls from adb for testing. I've tried this line

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:123456
```

but it creates outgoing calls and i need incoming. Is there a way to make incoming calls from adb on a physical device without emulator?

Comment: It's not a dublicate, the answers only work with emulator

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to connect 2 physical devices to the PC and make a call between them.
You can find their IDs by `adb devices` and then use
`adb -s [ID1] shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:123456` where ID1 is the ID of the caller.

Comment: This is still doing an outgoing call from [ID1]

Comment: Yes, that's what it is supposed to do. I am using 2 physical devices in order to initiate an incoming call to one of them.

Comment: I still have not managed to do it. I have both devices connected, with the code above I only get the outgoing call.

Comment: Are both devices registered to the network? Did you replace `123456` with the real number of the second device?